# All SAP Web IDE workspace projects have disappeared

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

On opening up the SAP Web IDE (Full Stack version) this morning, to my surprise all of my projects have been removed from my Workspace. I did have about 6 projects, which have now just disappeared.

Has anyone encountered this before / know a possible solution to get them back. It's only the trail SCP account, so I can't even get any support via SAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an ongoing issue where projects are still there but cannot be displayed. Happening to some users on the Full Stack version of the Web IDE, confirmed via thread on SAP Answers.